# how pass image in table view from local xml file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

Using the NSXMLParser i can retrieve the data from the local XML file, but the image path i had given in the XML file is not retrieving. The code below shows you in detail.

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Prices.xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
egsParser *theParser =[[egsParser alloc] initParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:theParser];
```

From this code i can parse the data but don't know how to retrieve the image along with this and show it in table view. The table view  code is as below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
 }


theLists = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = theLists.title;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

Kindly suggest an idea to parse and show the image in table view from local XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
 cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Image Link"]]];

or 

 cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Image Link"]]];
```

as per your code it will be like below.

```
 cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theList.imgUrl]]];
```

if you want to Retrive image from Saved Path

```
 cell.imageView.image= = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"yourSavedpath"];
```

Comment: can i give the XML file path in "Your Image Link" or i have to give the local path where i stored the image

Comment: You can give local path where the image stored as well as you can give the direct image link .

Comment: By adding images from server to table view may cause the loading slow .so you can download the image asynchroneously. Have a look on this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: am not getting this [NSURL URLWithString:theList.imgUrl] what i want to give in imgurl. As i stored my image something like this path /users/admin/imagefolder/image1.png   how can i give the img url for this

Comment: Try This  `UIImage *image; 
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: yourpath];`

Comment: This Worked out..                                                     image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: yourpath];                                                             Thank You so much Siba....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegate methods to parse the XML file...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
}
```

By using these delegate methods you get the your required element.

Comment: i already used these in parser file and retrieved the data too from XML. Also i can view it in table view too. All i need is to get the image from XML file and to show that in table view